# How to run a helper function multiple times for checking live results from the DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a forum project with Laravel 9, and I have made this helper function.

```
if(!function_exists('new_question')){
    function new_question($c) {
        $quelist = \DB::table('questions')->get();
        $quecount = $quelist->count();
        if($quecount > $c){
            return 'A new question is added.. please refresh the page..';
        }
    }
}
```

So it gets the number of current questions like this:

```
{{ new_question($queCnt); }}
```

And then, it will check if the `$quecount` equals `$queCnt` or not. And if not, then print the statement `A new question is added.. please refresh the page..`. Therefore the user will understand if any new question is added. But I need to run this helper function after some periods of time (for example, 10 seconds). However, I don't know how to call a function after a custom amount of time.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to implement lively updated UI. This requires your fronted to poll the server with some periods of time. So some Javscript should be involved, as Ali Usama said below.

Comment: @IliaYatsenko Yeah Javascript is involved but I need to call this php/laravel helper function in js scripts and this is the challenge

Comment: You need to write a function in JS, which will make an AJAX request to the server, where your PHP function will be executed, and render the received string, if it is not empty. Then call this JS with some interval, as Ali Usama said.

Comment: @IliaYatsenko Can you show me an example please

Comment: Added an answer with example

Comment: Well its not connected to the question but instead of getting all the database then count it. You can directly query the total question in the database by using `DB::table('questions')->count()`.

Comment: So you want to check if a new question is added in DB after a specified time and wants to inform the user and make him refresh the page so a new question will be available, is this the requirement?

Comment: @ArunP exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to figure out if the number of "content" has changed. Using Laravel, create a function that is accessible through a route, this function would return the number of posts, then, using javascript, you will call that function in an interval (example is 5 seconds) and if the number has changed since the last call, then there's new posts, so you should do some DOM manipulation to update your page to alert the user.

Your server side function would be simple, something like this:

```
function count_questions() {
        $quelist = DB::table('questions')->get();
        $quecount = $quelist->count();
        $response = array('quecount' => $quecount);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Then, identify how to reach this function through your routing table, and use the below jquery functions:

```
    var quecount = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                // change this URL to your path to the laravel function
                url: 'questions/count',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    // if queuecount is 0, then set its initial value to quecount
                    if(quecount == 0){
                        quecount = response.quecount;
                    }
                    if(response.quecount > quecount){
                        quecount = response.quecount;
                        new_question_found();
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
    function new_question_found(){
        $("#new_questions").html("New questions found");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**to run any function after a specific time, you have set the interval for example**

```
 // Call the new_question function every 10 seconds
 setInterval(new_question, 10000);
 // Use an AJAX request to call the new_question function on the 
 // server
function new_question(){
   $.ajax({
     url: '{{ url('/new_question') }}?c=10',
     success: function(response) {
     // Handle the response from the server
     console.log(response);
    }
   });
 }
</script>



// to receive get value update helper function 
if(!function_exists('new_question')){
  function new_question() {
   // Get the value of the c parameter from the query string
   $c = isset($_GET['c']) ? $_GET['c'] : 0;
   // Your code here...
  }
}
```

Comment: The question was about server-side function, so this needs a bit more complex approach.

Comment: `new_question` is a php/laravel helper function. How did you call a php/laravel function in js?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that is coming to my mind is may be too advance or too complex.

This solution need

- Laravel scheduler and queue (Jobs)
- and web push notification (ex : one-signal)

To reduce the traffic in the back-end you can have job to run like every 10 seconds in the back-end (Laravel scheduler and Queue).

If the question count get increased. you can call a api in the push notification and you can say there is a new question added.

the above work-flow is not explained well but this is in very simple term.

Answer (score 0):

For example:
on frontend side:

```
 const check_new_questions = function() {
     const message = 
         fetch('http://yourserver.com/new_questions_endpoint');
     if (message) {
         // show message
     }
 };
 // call each 10 seconds.
 setInterval(check_new_questions, 10000);
```

then on backend side:
create a route new_questions_endpoint which will call your function and return result as response.

But note, that receiving all the questions from the table each time could be expensive. Eloquent enables to make a count query without retrieving all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have this behaviour happen without any form of javascript.

The main way you could do this is by setting an interval via front-end like others have said. If you have any familiarity with APIs and general HTTP protocol, I would recommend you make an API route that calls your helper function; I also recommend responding with an empty body, and using the http status code to determine whether a refresh is needed: **200** for success and no refresh, **205** for success and refresh needed.

So you simply set a fetch api call on timeout, don't even need to decode the body and just use the response status to determine whether you need to run location.reload().

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement as per the comment you need to create an ajax request to BE from FE to check the latest question and based on that response you need to do it.

```
    setInterval(function()
{ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{url('/')}}/check/questions",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"action": "loadlatest", "id": id},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("Error:");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}, 10000);//time in milliseconds
```

the above js code will create an ajax request to Backend, below code will get the latest question 'id'.

```
$latest_id = DB::table('Questions')->select('id')->order_by('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

so either check it in BE and return a corresponding response to FE or return the latest id to FE and check it there.
then show the prompt to refresh or show a toast and refresh after 5 sec

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `function_exists()` ? I don't think it's useful in this case.

The easiest way to do what you want is to use ajax and `setInterval`

Front side:

```
const check_new_questions = function() {
     const data = 
         fetch('http://yourserver.com/new_questions_endpoint?c=current');
     if (data) {
         alert(your_message);
     }
 };
 // call each 10 seconds.
 setInterval(check_new_questions, 10000);
```

Back side:

```
function new_question() {
   // Get the value of the c parameter from the query string
   $c = isset($_GET['c']) ? $_GET['c'] : 0;
   $quelist = \DB::table('questions')->get();
   $quecount = $quelist->count();
   return ($quecount > $c);
  }
```

I suggest to use `c` as the last id and to not count questions but just to get the last question id. If they are different, one question or more was inserted.

**Attention** if you use this solution ( Ajax pulling ) you'll get two requests per 10 seconds per connected users. One for the ajax call and one for for the database call. If you have 10 users a day, it's ok but not if you have 10 thousands. A better but more complex approach is to use Mercure protocol or similar ( https://mercure.rocks/ ).